# Update para numerando em ordem coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde! estou com uma situação em meu serviço, sou iniciante em sql server e gostaria de um auxílio ou dica se possível. Tenho alguns registros (54) de uma tabela que precisam ser alterado seu código ordenando do 1 ao 54. Tentei utilizando declarar uma variável float, porém ao executar no banco de dados todos os registros da tabela na coluna "`CODIGOVENDA`" foram alterados para numeração "1". Estou utilizando a consulta à baixo:

```
DECLARE @CONTADOR FLOAT 
DECLARE @MAXIMO FLOAT 
SET @CONTADOR = 0 SET @MAXIMO = 54 
WHILE @CONTADOR < @MAXIMO 
UPDATE VENDAS SET CODIGOVENDA = @CONTADOR + 1
```

Poderia alguém me dar uma força sobre como realizar esse procedimento de modo correto, porfavor

Comment: Você tem alguma coluna para ordenar? Uma data da venda ou algo assim?

Comment: Muito estranha a forma como está fazendo, não é a forma usual de se trabalhar com SQL, mas, creio, que em algum lugar de sua procedure você tem que incrementar a variável @CONTADOR. Da maneira como está tudo indica que ficará num loop infinito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
UPDATE x
   SET x.CODIGOVENDA = x.NOVO_CODIGOVENDA
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODIGOVENDA) AS NOVO_CODIGOVENDA
      FROM VENDAS V
  ) x
 WHERE x.CODIGOVENDA IS NOT NULL;
```

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.

Answer (score 0):

Danilo, caso isso não tenha gerado um loop infinito, você deve ter uma outra linha dentro do while somando o @CONTADOR com ele mesmo mais um:

```
SET @CONTADOR = @CONTADOR + 1
```

Outro ponto importante, é que seu update sempre vai fazer o SET para todos os registros da tabela, você precisa verificar se tem alguma condição ( WHERE ) que pode ser feita, caso contrário, sempre após a execução, todos os registros vão ter o campo CODIGOVENDA iguais.